# How to get a static ip address on adsl

Tags: adsl, dsl, static-ip

I tried it before by setting the ip address manually. And I used this IP Address:

```
192.168.1.33
```

I reboot and tried if I can connect to the internet, but no luck.
It must be set to obtain your ip address automatically.
Is there any way on getting a static ip address on an adsl/dsl

Comment: The IP address you gave as an example is a private IP address, usually used by computers behind a router. Are you trying to setup a static IP address in your computer, or are you trying to setup a static IP address in your router or modem? Why do you want to use a static IP address instead of an automatically obtained IP address? This information will help us give you the best advice on what settings to change.

Comment: I just want to know if I can create 2 networks, one that accesses the internet and one that access router settings.
Because when I want to access router settings, and change the configuration. I cannot connect to the internet.

Comment: What is the brand name and model number of the the router or device you want to configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to request a static IP address from your ISP - they will walk you through configuring you ADSL modem.  You will have to pay extra for the privilege, though.